# What are metabase connections in the table analysis

Tags: connection, metabase

When I am looking at a "Question" in metabase (i.e. a database query), I can click on a book-like icon that says "Learn about your data".  Clicking on that icon opens up a view of all the tables in my current database.  When I click on a specific table, I see all the fields in that table.  At the top is a selector box that says "x FIELDS" and another that says "x CONNECTIONS".  Generally, it says "0 CONNECTIONS".  What do the "connections" refer to? I don't know what this is, and why it says ZERO?

Comment: Foreign keys, I'd imagine.

Comment: That's kind of what I think, but how do I make a connection then? How would I specifically make it go from "0 CONNECTIONS" to "1 CONNECTION".

Comment: You'd set up a foreign key?